# not able to suppress sqlplus output on terminal

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

I am using following script to delimited file using spool in the unix server. I ssh into it using putty and execute the shell script.

Here is shell script:

```
/oracle/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus -s /nolog<<-EOF

conn user/pass

SET PAGESIZE 0
SET LINESIZE 32000
SET NUMWIDTH 127
SET FEEDBACK OFF

set echo off
set heading off
set headsep off
SET MARKUP CSV ON DELIMITER | quote off
set termout off
spool mc_format.dat
select * from mytable;
spool off
EOF
```

but I am not able to suppress the rows printing out on the terminal, and eventually on log when I run using cron.

Is there any setting I am missing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-6EB80C8B-7B25-419C-AB5D-769544096001)
SET TERMOUT OFF

Controls the display of output generated by commands in a script that is executed with @, @@ or START. OFF suppresses the display so that you can spool output to a file without displaying the output on screen. ON displays the output on screen. TERMOUT OFF does not affect output from commands you enter interactively or redirect to SQL*Plus from the operating system.

So instead of the here document, call the script using one of the start methods mentioned.

Comment: Made it to work by using START quries.sql in my shell script. 

Thank you